# Are there any transactional Tables in the SAP Module MM?

Tags: sap-erp

Am I missing something? It seems to be the case that there is just Master Data.

I researched a lot, but all I find is the most detailed Information.

Could it be the Case that it's true (just Masterdata in MM) and the transactional Data is store in SD Tables?

I'm looking for Data about, for example, how many Products of Type X are in Plant Y (I need Key-Figures for an Analysis in SAP Analytics Cloud as a preparation for Projects).

Comment: yes there are transactional data in MM: material valuation (MBEW and MBEWH), material movements (MKPF and MSEG) and purchasing (EBAN and EKKO/EKPO)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's appreciated.